# Dependency property not getting registered in one specific control in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have two different controls, both of them have a property called Value. I am using pretty much the same code in both cases. And yet, in one case, I get binding error saying "Binding can be done only for dependency property in dependency object.

Below is the code to implement the dependency property

```
Public Class Calender
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Shared ValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", GetType(String), GetType(Calendar))
Public Property Value() As String
    Get
        If Not TryCast(Me.GetValue(ValueProperty), String) Is Nothing Then
            Return TryCast(Me.GetValue(ValueProperty), String)
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.SetValue(ValueProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
```

This is the exact same code I am using in another control. It works fine in that control, but in this case, it does not work. Also, when I use this Value property as

```
Value="{Binding MeasuringTapeCalibrationDue,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

it displays a squiggly line in XAML editor, saying "Value property was already registered by Calendar". I have the above code registering the value property just once.

Comment: try to rename the property.

Comment: That would require me to change a lot of places where this property is used. Can I just change ValueProperty part? Although, I don't think that is supported, but let me try just for the heck of it.

Comment: do you have the ReSharper? If so there is the refactory function to do that?

Comment: add ReadOnly at the declaration line.

Comment: Ok, tried both. Still the same issue. Somehow whenever I am binding the property, XAML keeps warning saying "property is already registered".

Comment: if i'll try to resolve it, the solution will be in c#. it is good for you?

Comment: Sure. Language is not an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92862/discussion-between-i-a-golik-and-jitendra-garg).

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `GetType(Calendar)` by `GetType(OtherControl)` in the dependency property registration in the other control:

```
Public Class OtherControl

Public Shared ValueProperty As DependencyProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("Value", GetType(String), GetType(OtherControl))
```